# Sparse matrix computational difficulties

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, singularity-theory, sparse-matrices

I am a computer science student. But I start writing here because my problem is not code related. It is purely computational related.

I am trying to calculated inverse of a large (e.g., $2000 \times 2000$) square matrix.  This matrix is band diagonal matrix.

The non zero elements are very small numbers (e.g: $1--6$). They never exceed 6.

Now when I invert this matrix the result of inversion are all same number displayed.

Output:

```
9.711E013  9.711E013  9.711E013  9.711E013....................
9.711E013  9.711E013  9.711E013  9.711E013......................

9.711E013  9.711E013  9.711E013  9.711E013.....................
..............................................................

 9.711E013  9.711E013  9.711E013  9.711E013
```

My question is that why this type of output I get? What is the mathematical reason behind this?

Comment: what are you using to invert it? Matlab, for example, should be easily inverting this.

Comment: I am using universal java matrix package for matrix inversion. I write down this code in java.

Comment: You should post your code, I don't think we have enough information to see what's going wrong.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2872771/sparse-matrix-inversion-some-time-singular-some-time-get-a-big-value    Please go through this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:** thanks to comment of copper.hat.

The mathematical/numerical reason is that the condition number defined as 
$$
\varkappa(A) = \frac{\sigma_{\max}(A)}{\sigma_{\min}(A)}
$$
is too large, say of order $10^{10}$ or even more. $\sigma_{\min, \max}(A)$ is the minimal and maximal [singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value) of matrix $A$.

The case of small determinant is a particular case and in some cases implied from the argument above.

Comment: This doesn't explain why all the entries in the output are the same, though.

Comment: My guess would be that this number is the “infinity” of used software.

Comment: I used intellj idea to write down java code and use universal java matrix package to invert this matrix.

Comment: A small determinant does not necessarily translate into ill conditioned. Generally the issue is because the condition number is large, which is related to the singular values, not the eigenvalues.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2872771/sparse-matrix-inversion-some-time-singular-some-time-get-a-big-value   Please go through this link where I explain my code.