# Sparse Matrix inversion some time singular some time get a big value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, singularity, sparse-matrices, lu-decomposition

I want to invert a matrix which is a "band" diagonal matrix. The structure of the matrix is

[image]

The blue strip represents the elements that are non zero.All other element in white area are of zero value.

I write down the code in java to represent non zero elements.

```
 import org.ujmp.core.Matrix;

public class Omegatest {
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
    Matrix omega= Matrix.Factory.zeros(2000,2000);
    Matrix Bigomega=Matrix.Factory.zeros(2000,2000);
    for(int k1=0;k1<1999;k1++){
        omega.setAsDouble(1, k1, k1);
        omega.setAsDouble(-1, k1, k1 + 1);
        omega.setAsDouble(-1, k1 + 1, k1);
        omega.setAsDouble(1, k1 + 1, k1 + 1);
        Bigomega = Bigomega.plus(omega);
        omega.clear();
    }
    System.out.println(Bigomega.inv());

}
```

}

Now whenever I try to invert this matrix, it gives me an error that the matrix is singular.

If I slightly change the code and take two Sparse Matrix instead of normal matrix it gives me a big value like 1902.003 1903.005 in each cells.

I know there is a definite problem in the code.

But first I want to know the mathematical explanation of this two conditions.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it a full rank matrix? In other words, if I am interpreting it correctly, the size of this square matrix is $2000 \times 2000$. If correct, then the rank should be $2000$. Also, you can check whether all the absolute of eigenvalues are positive $|\lambda_i| > 0$ and the condition number is low, i.e., $\frac{\max\{|\lambda_i|\}}{\min\{|\lambda_i|\}}$...

Comment: Yes it is a square matrix with 2000*2000 dimension

Comment: Ok. The rank of a matrix? If it's less than 2000, then you have a problem with the invertibility.

Comment: As per my programming the rank should be 2000. If its rank < 2000 that means its determinant are zero right.

Comment: yes, if it's low rank, then the determinant will be zero (i.e., some eigenvalues are zero). If the eigenvalues are nearly zero (but not really zero), then the condition number of a matrix might be high which causes the numerical problem with the inversion of a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of the elements in each row (or column) is zero, hence the matrix is not invertible. The matrix looks like this
$$
\pmatrix{ 1 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
&\ddots& \ddots&\ddots\\
&&\ddots& \ddots&\ddots\\
&&&-1 & 2 & -1 \\
&&&&1 & -1 
}
$$

(It seems to be some sort of stiffness matrix for a differential equation with Neumann boundary conditions, where constant functions are in the null space.)

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.Is there any method to invert this type of matrix?

Comment: This is possible if and only if you can divide by zero. Hence: No.